# How to expand group with JSLink custom list views

Tags: 2013, list-view, jslink, grouping

If I custom render my groups on list views with JSLink, I (of course) overwrite the SharePoint standard code, including the javascript for expanding.

```
function myGrouping(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, expand) {
        var html = listItem[group] + '<br/>';
        return html;
}
```

I already tried to copy the default SP js into my code but it won't work. Is there a simple way to expand the group and load the items into the ctx object?

Answer (score 1):

*of the top of my head, don't have acces to my own code library*

```
RenderGroupTemplate(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, collapse)
```

returns the standard HTML, you would then use some string functions to work your HTML in there

```
function mygroupTemplate(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, collapse) {
    console.info('groupTemplate', group, groupId, level, collapse, listItem, listSchema);
    var H=RenderGroupTemplate(ctx, group, groupId, listItem, listSchema, level, collapse);
    console.info(H);
    return H;
};
```

or manipluate the listItem object going into that `RenderGroupTemplate` function